# sql delete / cleanup procedure for zip files older than 1 day

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql stored procedure that creates zip files every hour and places them into a D:/----/outputFolder (with the help of a job to run the stored procedure hourly).

I am wondering how I can write a delete/cleanup procedure to delete the zip files older than 1 day every night at midnight.

Comment: create a sql server agent job that can do that.  you don't need a stored proc for that.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply!